# What is the simplest way to create python flask swagger

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have written `python` program with some `flask rest` logic, and I want to know what is the easiest way to create `flask swagger` from it? I saw many tutorials with different `packages` but in my opinion they include too much manual work. Is there a `package` which does in 1 or 2 steps?

Comment: Which packages have you looked at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any fully automated approaches that you can just apply after-the-fact.
I suspect that for Flask the best you can do is something like [Flask-RESTPlus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io). But there are, as you say, others.

Side note: I have myself switched from using Flask to using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) instead, partly because it has OpenAPI specification (a.k.a Swagger) support built in, but it has some other nifty features too.

Comment: I approved the solution, but I must admit I wasn't able to use ` Flask-RESTPlus`. each time I got new exception. starting with `ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug'` which requires downgrade the plugin, and then `function' object has no attribute 'as_view`